# how to make the text from flex to straight?

Tags: css

I did this random quotes project, but I can't make the text in button appears straight. I don't know why it is flex.

[this text inside the second green box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qd0P.png)

I want to make it straight

Comment: please share [mcve] in OP

Answer (score 0):

Set button `width` to `min-width: fit-content;`

Answer (score 0):

add to css file:

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

and remove this:

```
 #button {
display:flex;
}
```

and edit button like this:

```
    button{
    widht:100%;
    background-color:chartreuse;
    border:solid 0px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```